# Django NoReverseMatch newbie

Tags: django, view, django-urls

I am trying to create a reply page for a forum thread. The forum views and the thread views work fine but I am having trouble setting up the reply and start new thread pages. Have managed to create a thread and forum.

Here is my views.py:

```
def post(request, ptype, pk):
    """Display a post form."""
    action = reverse("webnotes.forum.views.%s" % ptype, args=[pk])
    if ptype == "new_thread":
        title = "Start New Topic"
        subject = ''
    elif ptype == "reply":
        title = "Reply"
        subject = "Re: " + Thread.objects.get(pk=pk).title

    return render_to_response("forum/post.html",add_csrf(request,subject=subject,action=action, title=title))


def new_thread(request, pk):
    """Start a new thread."""
     p = request.POST
    if p["subject"] and p["body"]:
        forum = Forum.objects.get(pk=pk)
        thread = Thread.objects.create(forum=forum,title=p["subject"],creator=request.user)
        Post.objects.create(thread=thread, title=p["subject"],body=p["body"],creator=request.user)
     return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("webnotes.forum.views.forum", args=[pk]))


def reply(request, pk):
    """Reply to a thread."""
    p = request.POST
    if p["body"]:
        thread = Thread.objects.get(pk=pk)
        post = Post.objects.create(thread=thread,title=p["subject"],body=p["body"],creator=request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("webnotes.forum.views.thread", args=[pk])+"?page=last")
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
url(r"^post/(new_thread|reply)/(\d+)/$", "forum.views.post"),
url(r"^post/reply/(\d+)/$", "forum.views.reply"),
url(r"^post/new_thread/(\d+)/$", "forum.views.new_thread"),
```

When I go to http://localhost:8000/post/reply/1/, I get:

Reverse for 'webnotes.forum.views.reply' with arguments '(u'1',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

I also found this to be in the traceback:

```
action = reverse("webnotes.forum.views.%s" % ptype, args=[pk])
```

which corresponds with the views.py. What could be wrong? I hope I have made this clear. If any additional information is required, I will be happy to provide.

P.S. I am following the tutorial on this website: http://www.lightbird.net/dbe/forum1.html

Answer (score 2):

Your reverse is looking up `"webnotes.forum.views.thread"` but your URLconf has `"forum.views.new_thread"`.

Generally, you should give your URLs [names](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#url) and use those in the call to reverse.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, doesn't my reverse look up reverse("webnotes.forum.views.%s" % ptype, args=[pk])?

Comment: Yes, your define url "forum.views.reply" but you reverse "webnotes.forum.views.reply". That's two different strings.

Comment: I am using url(r"^post/(new_thread|reply)/(\d+)/$","forums.views.post",name ='forum_post') with reverse("forum_post", args=[ptype,pk]) but no luck.

Comment: What about with args=['reply', 23] ? If that works then your ptype or pk values do not match the regxp. Also please update your code in the question.